# Switch off linux running only on RAM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm working on an Embedded board that has a battery to keep the system alive in case of power fail, if I detect a power fail I just need to flush all and switch off the system.
The problem is that the NAND(/dev/root) is not powered by the battery, so I don't have access to NAND memory, I manage to flush all my data thanks to some capacitors that gives me about 200ms to save and flush all but then I can't switch off the system I guess because Linux tries to access to /dev/root that is not powered up, is there a way to switch off the system without writing anything into /dev/root during the shutting down?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is a very interesting design. why is nand rootfs excluded from the ups system?

Comment: But to answer your question: you can use `u` command in `sysrq` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) to re-mount file system as "read-only". After that, your file system is safe against power loss but your system will function almost OK and can be shutdown gracefully. Or if you don't think you have time to gracefully shutdown or there's such a bad consequence for a power loss during shutdown process that you would prefer a artificial power loss to avoid it, then you can use `o` command.

Comment: *"I can't switch off the system I guess because ..."* -- So the basis of your question is your guessing (rather than established fact)?